# Building from source using:"pip install ." doesn't work with sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pip

I'll first mention I'm using ubuntu 16.04.
I have a simple but painful problem, I cloned a repo:
https://github.com/huggingface/transformers,
Now I want to install it from source using:

```
pip install .
```

As mentioned in the repo.
Sadly I got this error:

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: >'/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tokenizers-0.7.0.dist-info'
>   Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Fair enough, so I tried, as I always do when it complains about permission issues:

```
sudo pip install .
```

This gave this error:

> Invalid requirement: '.'

So apparently he didn't like my sudo, no hard feeling, the last thing I tried was to do:

```
sudo -s
```

and then the "pip install .", but still hates me.
I know that something simple and stupid, but I can't figure it out, and searching a query with '.' inside made it harder.

Thanks, I'll be happy for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Errno+13+Permission+denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the package into the user directory with `pip install . --user`

Comment: I knew it was simple..
If I could give you vote up , I would.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries, just mark the answer as a solution if it helped you solve your problem